# Conditional run steps in GitHub workflows

Tags: github, continuous-integration

GitHub actions has been pretty painless up until now where it has become painful.

The documentation is pretty poor regarding very specific tasks.

I would like to:

1. Run a `run` step on a pull request (and updates on that pull request) *and* on updates to the master branch.
2. Run a `run` step on a tagged commit on the master branch.

The furthest I've gotten so far is:

```
- name: Something
  if: github.event.pull_request
  run: echo 'hello'
```

Comment: Any progress? I'm having a similar situation where I only want certain run steps to execute if certain files have been modified. You can set up a whole workflow to only run if certain files are modified, but I want to just do it all in the one container.

Comment: @PavelKomarov Ooo that would be interesting to know also. I did fix my original question with the `if` stating if the branch was on `master` and was a `pull request`. I would also like to know the answer to your question!

Comment: Yeah, I got it. Here's the [build.yml](https://github.com/pavelkomarov/projection-pursuit/blob/master/.github/workflows/build.yml). I have to take on a dependency to `tj-actions/changed-files@v6.3`, but then I can use an `if` to make my `LaTeX stuff` step optional. Since you answered your question for yourself, post it here for the public.